# Rails redirect path/? to path/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some users coming to www.mysite.com/?

The cookie is saved however i am unable to redirect user to / path after the action is done.

I tried on index and also on show, what would be the best way to do it?
I cant do it via htaccess or similar..

> www.mysite.com/?
>
> redirect to www.mysite.com

```
  def index
    session[:id] = 'home'

    if params[:id] == '?'
      redirect_to "/", :error => { :success => 'message'}
    end

  end
```

Comment: I don't believe the `?` will be viewed by Rails as the `params[:id]`, because `?` is a reserved character in a URL that begins the url_params

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most [Rails request methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html) totally ignore just a single `?` in the URL. The query string is available in the `params` methods only when you have a more "complete" query like, for example `?something` or `?something=true`.

I was able to detect it using `request.env['REQUEST_URI']`, so you can try something like this:

```
if request.env['REQUEST_URI'] == 'http://yourwebsite.com/?'
  redirect_to "/", :error => { :success => 'message'}
end
```

Comment: Did you mean to leave off the `?` in your test?